# Таблички " Уходя гасите свет! " , " Уходя выключайте воду! "

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

В фильме на глаза попалась табличка на стене: **Уходя гасите свет!**

Стало интересно: почему нет запятой?
Оказывается, не мне одной интересно.

*В классе, на двери висят распечатанные на принтере таблички:

**Уходя гасите** **свет**,  **Уходя выключайте воду**.*

Мама спрашивает: [**Это важно или это мои тараканы?**](https://conf.7ya.ru/fulltext-thread.aspx?cnf=Care7&trd=14569)

Из рекламы продукции:

- 14531 Самоклеющаяся табличка. **Уходя гасите свет** (100х200)
  [Магазин нормативно-правовой литературы и пожарно-технического оборудования.]
- *Уходит последний сотрудник домой, а "уходя гасите свет" табличка у него перед глазами. Вот вам и инвестиции в энергосбережения!*

А как правильно? Есть ли какие-то особенности для табличек?

Answer (score 3):

Никаких особенностей для знаков препинания на табличках нет, проблема в том, что закон экономии средств в современном мире влияет и на необязательность соблюдения правил пунктуации. Хотя вон в Вашем примере из рекламы необязательна оказалась и орфография:

```
 14531 Самоклеющаяся табличка. "Уходя гасите свет" (100х200). 
[ Магазин   нормативно-правовой литературы и пожарно-технического оборудования ]
```

СамоклеЯщаяся - клеить -2 спряжение.

Но сейчас это никого не останавливает.Ошибок много везде. У нас в маршрутках до сих пор висит объявление, написанное грамотеем транспортной конторы:"Проездной билет действителен при предъявлении документа, удостоверяющего личность, заверенную органом выдавшей документ". Мой вопрос "Каким же органом и чьим заверять личность?" так и остался без ответа, кое-кто хихикнул, но бредятину не сняли, всем оказалось всё понятно.

Говорят, что грамотность не главное, главное, чтобы было ярко и понятно, а мы понимаем всё,даже если буквы в слове перепутаем местами, сохраним первую и последнюю, остальное догадаемся: "Отсаонвитесь на трутоаре".

Прочитали ведь? Значит, всё понятно.

В поликлинике висят таблички вообще без знаков препинания. В магазинах сплошная безграмотность. В общем, грамотность никому не нужна, никто за ней не следит, никто ничему не удивляется, а такие, как мы, даже осуждаются: "Что, грамотная очень? Вот возьми и напечатай грамотно, а нам и так сойдёт"

И здесь та же ситуация. Обидно только, что до школы докатилось, там у Вас пример из таблички в школе. Таких учителей гнать надо, как в фильме, помните, директор не взял на работу учительницу, говорившую "на транвае"

Comment: Это все хорошо, но почему Вы обошли вниманием вопрос о том, в каких случаях деепричастие не обособляется?  В самом общем виде это правило говорит о "едином целом", которое составляют деепричастие со сказуемым (ни "одиночное", ни даже "образ действия" не являются при этом строго обязательными признаками). Здесь, имхо, тот самый, случай. Во всяком случае - так можно воспринимать.

Comment: @Людмила  Статья так и называется: " Это важно или это мои тараканы? ", я только дала из нее цитату.  То же самое касается и рекламы: привела в тексте вопроса ТАК, КАК ЕСТЬ,  ничего не изменяла... А грамотность?  Для МОЕЙ страны - это вообще нонсенс.

Comment: Деепричастие может не обособляться,если оно превращается в наречие, но тогда оно обычно стоит в конце предложения и может быть заменено наречием, об этом написал Niemand с примерами(смеясь = весело).Здесь как раз не тот случай, здесь обычное деепричастие уходя = когда уходишь, явная глагольность без намёка на качество.

Answer (score 2):

Из современной поэзии http://www.stihi.ru/2014/07/29/3820

**Уходя,** гасите свет,
Выключайте все приборы,
Прекращайте разговоры
На ближайшие пять лет.
Дверь закройте, **уходя,**
На замок в два оборота
И идите за ворота
Вдаль – куда глаза глядят.

**В художественном тексте стоит запятая, это деепричастие.** Оно здесь имеет значение условия или времени (если/когда  вы уходите).

**Кстати, Розенталь именно в этом предложении (в соответствии с основным правилом) предлагает ставить запятую**:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113

"Одиночное деепричастие обособляется, если сохраняет значение глагольности, выступая в функции второстепенного сказуемого, указывая на время действия, его причину, условие и т. д. (но не на образ действия): **Уходя, гасите свет**: (когда гаси́те?)"

Но народ Розенталя не читает и далеко не всегда ставит здесь запятую, для него главное –  **паузы-то нет!**   Даже на форумах дружно выступают против запятой. Таблички же  – **текст делового стиля,** и деепричастие при такой записи вполне  может выполнять  функцию наречия: при выходе/уходе из дома гасите свет.

Интересно, что предложение "УходЯ, выключйте вОду" имеет меньше шансов остаться без запятой: при наличии четырехсложного глагола пауза как раз присутствует. Так что значение значением, а **структура предложения  и объём фразы имеют весьма существенное влияние на постановку знаков препинания**.

Comment: Кто такая Татьяна Костопулу... Нешто это аргумент? И потом – ладно, пунктуация от интонации зависит, но чтоб ещё и от стиля речи?! Следующим будет тембр голоса?

Comment: Уважаемый @Niemand, предлагаю Вам воздержаться от просторечных выражений  в ваших комментариях и излагать мысли только по конкретному содержанию ответа. Ваш юмор приберегите для других случаев, иначе мне придется использовать "тревожную кнопку".  А Вы меня всё больше удивляете в части ваших познаний: не в курсе, что лексика, грамматика, знаки препинания зависят от стиля речи? И вообще, работайте больше над своими ответами, иногда их просто неловко читать. И куда только модераторы смотрят?! Надоел Ваш развязный стиль.

Comment: Знаки препинания от стиля речи не зависят, если исключить т.наз. "авторскую пунктуацию" ("Это звучит – гордо!" и т.п.)

Comment: А вот исключать ничего не надо. И авторская пунктуация - это не "так называемая", а целое явление в русском языке, ею известные ученые-филологи занимаются.  И деловую речь не забудьте: к примеру, обстоятельственные обороты в начале деловых писем чаще всего не обособляются.

Comment: Sibylla, деепричастие оно ***всегда***, стоит запятая или не стоит.  Просто деепричастие одиночное деепричастие не обособляется. Но в целом согласен, с Niemand'ом не спорьте, бесполезно. Он все сведет к тому, что вам надо посмотреть в учебник (которого сам не открывал). По поводу стиля и авторской пунктуации надо просто разобраться, что именно под этими терминами понимать.  Авторская пунктуация не значит неправильная, это те случаи, когда автор ради пояснения мыли выбирает не противоречащую общим правилам, но необычную пунктуацию. А авторы ингогда просто вилдят "глагольность", где не видит Р.

Comment: >> *Просто одиночное деепричастие не обособляется.* Г-н Morkovkin, и после этого вы еще наезжаете на Niemanda? Свожу опять к тому, что вам надо посмотреть в учебник.

Comment: @Niemand *после этого вы еще наезжаете на* На Вас никто специально не наезжает. Как только перестанете задирать нос,  учить других и демонстративно нарушать принятые правила общения, милости просим в общество цивилизованного обсуждения.

Answer (score 2):

**Рассуждение о том, как деепричастие "теряет" глагольные свойства (моё личное понимание вопроса)**

**Я очень люблю Розенталя:** он гений в своей области, иначе и не скажешь. Его заслуга в том, что он создал практическую орфографию на основании Правил 1956 года.

**Но наука не стоит на месте, и не всё, созданное им, является абсолютной истиной.** Прежде всего, надо отметить, что Розенталь семантике при решении пунктуационных задач придавал преимущественное значение, **а это далеко не так**.

Безусловно, важна общая семантика сообщения, а она очень во многом зависит **от структуры предложения.** Деепричастие переходит/не переходит в наречие не оттого, что оно теряет/сохраняет глагольные свойства, а оттого, что **оно в структуре предложения занимает место наречия. Это — главное.**

Вот и в **современных правилах Лопатина** мы читаем, что изменение порядка слов влияет на эту самую глагольность. **А следующим этапом понимания будет то, что глагольность здесь и вовсе ни при чем**, так как деепричастие в любом случае является формой глагола и семантику действия сохраняет. Соответственно, "глагольность без намека на качество" и другие подобные рассуждения — всё это выдуманные истории, **а правит всем структурная форма.**

У Лопатина:
*По дорожке сада он шел не оглядываясь. — Не оглядываясь, он шел по дорожке сада.*
Ну какая тут утрата или сохранение глагольности!?
**Просто деепричастие удобно обособить при одной структуре и неудобно — при другой.**

[**Знаки препинания при обособленных обстоятельствах**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121)

Comment: Прошла по Вашей ссылке. И что вижу? " Деепричастия и деепричастные обороты не обособляются:1) если деепричастие непосредственно примыкает к глаголу и имеет значение образа действия: Не спеша бегут лошади среди зеленых холмистых полей (Бун.) — бегут как?; Такие деепричастия по функции сближаются с наречием:  Ср. при изменении порядка слов и в результате — подчеркнутом усилении глагольности (обозначении действия):   По дорожке сада он шел не оглядываясь. — Не оглядываясь, он шел по дорожке сада"

Comment: Объяснение-то всё-таки основано на утрате глагольности и приобретении значения наречия как? , а не что делая? Так что Ваше "Ну какая тут утрата или сохранение глагольности" повисает в воздухе. Структурная форма как раз и придаёт глагольность или забирает её. Это и по Лопатину, и по Розенталю - одинаково

Comment: И вообще, рано списываете Розенталя, новое - хорошо забытое старое, что-то не вижу, что новые знания его перечеркнули, если только запутали его ясные объяснения. А Лопатина Вы просто не дочитали до конца, он здесь ничего нового не внёс.

Comment: Автор  строит текст по смыслу, определяя функцию деепричастия (1) или как добавочного  сообщения, описывающую дополнительную ситуацию, (2) или как обстоятельства в простом предложении. Реализует свое решение он в виде структуры предложения, позволяющей обособить или не обособить деепричастие. Если работать с ГОТОВЫМ предложением, то структур уже ЗАДАНА автором,  и решение определяется по ней. Это  и есть то НОВОЕ, что желательно было бы Вам понять.

Comment: И еще небольшое замечание: некорректно на форуме использовать такую лексику, как "не дочитали, не так поняли, не разобрались". Вы же всё-таки не со ШКОЛЬНИКАМИ имеете дело,  здесь взрослые люди, которые могут иметь собственное мнение, отличное от Вашего.  Я тоже могу предположить, что Вы "просто не дочитали Лопатина", но как-то неловко об этом говорить.

Comment: Что ж, извините, коль задела Ваше самолюбие, но это защитная реакция на "Соответственно, "глагольность без намека на качество" и другие подобные рассуждения — всё это выдуманные истории","Ну какая тут утрата или сохранение глагольности! " Ваше "оригинальное" мнение всегда пытается перечеркнуть чьё-то, а мы просто сопротивляемся, потому что до истины в последней инстанции всё ж далековато.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, сэкономили на запятой... Она, разумеется, нужна. Сравните:

**Она идет по жизни смеясь.**

**Уходя, гасите свет.**

Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: Хороша экономия....

Comment: Обособленные обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами, при резком их отделении от главного слова может выделяться с помощью тире.

Comment: Пример:  Сняв голову - не приставишь.